# Providing security to user uploaded files

Tags: php, web-services, .htaccess, security, encryption

I have a website in PHP, in which I want to secure user uploaded images and files, either by encryption/decryption or by providing password security to corresponding directory.

So that only that user can see it and others will not be able to see or download it.

I have tried to secure it using .htaccess, it restricted outside user from accessing that directory. However I am passing those image links to Android and iOS APP. Due to restriction given by .htaccess those APP are not able to display those images.

Kindly let me know if you have any suggestion to secure it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you place the uploaded images into a folder that is not publicly accessible, and create a script getimg.php or something to that extent, that checks the current user can access that image, and if they can then, then do something like this to serve the image:

```
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg"); 
$file = file_get_contents("/path/to/filestore/user2/file.jpg");
header("Content-Length: ".strlen($file));
echo $file;
exit();
```

You could return a 403 forbidden if the user does not have access

```
header("HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden");
echo $errorMessage;
exit();
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, Using .htaccess I have done same thing in different way. However problem starts when I pass image link to mobile app through web service.

Will I be able to access image from publicly restricted directory in APP?

Comment: You will only access the image via the php script, it will be publicly accessible, however it will make the decision on whether access is allowable or not. Something like `example.com/getimg.php?img=mypic2.jpg`

Comment: I just tried this solution it works fine, however my main concern is still open. It is not secure as any one can access files once he get this kind of url example.com/getimg.php?img=mypic2.jpg.

Comment: Well to ensure security you would need to create some unique session via some sort of login or authentication to the web server. You could then use a userid or similar to identify who has accesss to what resource